# install packages in ubuntu

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu

I wonder if there is a convenient way to install packages on Ubuntu, except through `tlmgr`. I cannot find many packages with `apt-get install` texlive-package, don't know why. As for manual installation, it's too complicated and since the packages have all different files (.ino .sty .dtx...). I don't know what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what problem you are having with the Debian/Ubuntu TeX Live packages. Norbert Preining and others have gone to a lot of trouble to make sure these packages work well. The major issue is that the packages get outdated. I think most people here would recommend a manual installation, but I use the TeX Live Debian packages and they work fine.

If you want a simple way to install the TeX Live Debian packages, you could just install the meta-package `texlive-full`. This installs a lot of stuff that you won't need, but if disk space is not a concern, then that is the simplest way to go. You may also find [LaTeX: Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Latex) useful.

OTOH, the list of packages I have installed is as follows. These probably include most of the packages required for basic usage. I am currently using Debian wheezy (stable).

```
ii  texlive-base                         2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries                     2012.20120628-4         amd64                   Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-common                       2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Base component
ii  texlive-doc-base                     2012.20120611-1         all                     TeX Live: TeX Live documentation
ii  texlive-extra-utils                  2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: TeX auxiliary programs
ii  texlive-font-utils                   2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Graphics and font utilities
ii  texlive-fonts-extra                  2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Extra fonts
ii  texlive-fonts-extra-doc              2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-extra
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended            2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Recommended fonts
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended-doc        2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-recommended
ii  texlive-generic-recommended          2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Recommended generic packages
ii  texlive-latex-base                   2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Basic LaTeX packages
ii  texlive-latex-base-doc               2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-base
ii  texlive-latex-extra                  2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages
ii  texlive-latex-extra-doc              2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-extra
ii  texlive-latex-recommended            2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
ii  texlive-latex-recommended-doc        2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-recommended
ii  texlive-luatex                       2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: LuaTeX packages
ii  texlive-pictures                     2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Graphics packages and programs
ii  texlive-pictures-doc                 2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pictures
ii  texlive-pstricks                     2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: PSTricks packages
ii  texlive-pstricks-doc                 2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pstricks
ii  texlive-science                      2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Typesetting for natural and computer sciences
ii  texlive-science-doc                  2012.20120611-2         all                     TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-science
ii  texlive-xetex                        2012.20120611-5         all                     TeX Live: XeTeX packages
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple way to have a full TeX installation and also have `tlmgr` and you want apt to be aware of it (so it doesn't install dependencies that you already have), you can do it with one command

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

First you have to clone the repo to get the script:

```
git clone https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu
```

If you want to use the Ubuntu repository packages, a good way of finding what you need is to use `apt-file`. Suppose you get an error saying that you are missing `ocherokee.sty`. Then run this command:

```
$ apt-file find ocherokee.sty
texlive-omega: /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/lambda/base/ocherokee.sty
```

Note that when you install `apt-file` you first need to run the following command:

```
apt-file update
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install texlive-full you will get the whole texlive distribution.

For example, `apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` will install hundreds of latex package:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/texlive-latex-extra

I've never had to use `tlmgr` to install a package on ubuntu (only except if I needed the up-to-date version).